# PHP data became empty after json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have the following php code. I am able to get the value stored in my variable and printed. But after json_encode, the value became 'empty'. Is there a bug in json_encode ? I am using Php 7.2 on ubuntu 18

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.thestar.com.my/rss/news/nation');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$rss = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$cnt = count($rss->channel->item);
$items = array();
$items[0]['title'] = $rss->channel->item[0]->title;
$items[0]['url'] = $rss->channel->item[0]->link;
echo $items[0]['title'] . PHP_EOL;
echo $items[0]['url'] . PHP_EOL;
echo json_encode($items) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

See the output below. What is wrong with the json_encode ? Why after the json_encode, the title became empty ?

```
Sabah updates SOPs for places of worship and childcare centres
https://www.thestar.com.my/news/nation/2021/06/13/sabah-updates-sops-for-places-of-worship-and-childcare-centres
[{"title":{"0":{}},"url":{"0":"https:\/\/www.thestar.com.my\/news\/nation\/2021\/06\/13\/sabah-updates-sops-for-places-of-worship-and-childcare-centres"}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

`json_encode` produces an empty object tag (`{}`) when passed PHP objects that do not implement `JsonSerializable` or contain public member variables.

You pass it `\SimpleXMLElement` nodes, not strings.

In your `echo` it just shows because the XML entities implement `__toString()` which echo invokes.

Either do that aswell or cast it to `(string)`:

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$items = array();
$items[0]['title'] = $rss->channel->item[0]->title->__toString();
$items[0]['url'] = (string) $rss->channel->item[0]->link;
echo json_encode($items) . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Got it !! Thanks. Appreciated very much

Comment: Found out another method too. $items[0]['title'] = utf8_encode($rss->channel->item[0]->title); Thank you.

Comment: It would also work with `trim`, many methods force string conversion of the input. `utf8_encode` however is not something you should just put around everything. If the input was already UTF8 encoded then you destroy special characters with it by double-encoding.

Comment: `utf8_encode()` is a misnamed function that converts from ISO-8859-1. If you aren't using ISO-8859-1 it'll just corrupt your data.

Comment: @Jsmidt If your question is solved by that I'd appreciate marking the answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks..Got it with

```
$items[0]['title'] = $rss->channel->item[0]->title->__toString();
```